# Вывести среднее значение произвольного поля по конкретному пользователю

Tags: wordpress, метаданные

В wordpress в каждой записи присваивается автор, в каждой записи есть произвольное поле "rehub_review_overall_score".

rehub_review_overall_score - является рейтингом (1-10), может выводиться так: 7.3

Как можно вывести среднее значение по конкретному пользователю со всех записей? По-сути получится общий рейтинг пользователя.

Там где я хочу вывести общий рейтинг, автор определяется переменной:

```
$author_ID = bp_displayed_user_id();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать?

Comment: Что означает произвольное поле в вашей формулировке? По мне это поле более чем конкретное.

Comment: Подразумеваю именно произвольные поля https://codex.wordpress.org/Произвольные_поля

Как включаются в админке: http://www.lead-woman.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/13-08-2014-15-19-05.png

Как выглядят в админке: http://missudacha.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/ПроизвольныеПоля.png

Например чтобы вывести произвольное поле на страницу можно использовать код:
<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rehub_offer_product_price_old', true)); ?>